# An anchor # and a filtering # at the same time in the url (HTML + CSS + JQuery)

Tags: jquery, html, url, anchor, jquery-isotope

I am using Isotope (http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) for filtering on my website and I applied its feature when using a filter gives you a /index.html#filter=.filtername ending to the url line (more info about it at the bottom of this page: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/filtering.html) . It is working like a charm (thanks Isotope team, amazing work), but it disables fully functioning anchors.

I wish to achieve that from a page you can go directly to an anchor on a different site (for example index.html) with a filter active. Something like this:

**/index.html#filter=.filtername#anchorname**

Separately (active filter OR anchor-link) it is working as it should (*/index.html#filter=.filtername* OR */index.html#anchorname*).

Just to make sure it's clear enough what I try to achieve:

1. You are on a page /page.html and you click on a link that
2. Gets you to a specific part (anchor) of /index.html but also adds the Isotope filtering

Any ideas on how to proceed?